# Solving the equation $\displaystyle \frac{e^x}{x}=\int_n^{n+1}f(t)\,dt$

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration, limits, functional-equations

Suppose the equation $\displaystyle \frac{e^x}{x}=\int_n^{n+1}f(t)\,dt$ as $f(t)=\frac{e^t}{t}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N} \setminus{0}$.

How to prove that:

- The equation above has a unique solution $U_n$ on $[n,n+1]$.
- The $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{U_n}{n}=1$.

Comment: See the [mean value theorem for integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_integration). For the second part, what are the highest and lowest possible values of $U_n/n$ for each $n$?

Comment: I have to ask how this Question makes sense.  The "equation" left side depends only on $x$ and not on $n$, the right side depends only on $n$ and not on $x$ (though conceivably the right side depends on an unknown function $f$ as well, despite the OP's statement that $f(t) = \frac{e^t}{t}$).

Comment: You can treat the right hand set as constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\, dt$

Then $\int_n^{n+1}f(t)\,dt = F(n+1)-F(n)$ and $f=F'$

So by the mean value theorem, you have $U_n \in [n,n+1]$ so that $F'(U_n)=\cfrac{F(n+1)-F(n)}{(n+1)-n}$

---

$n \le U_n \le n+1$

$1 \le \cfrac{U_n}{n} \le 1+\cfrac{1}{n} \underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} 1$

So $\cfrac{U_n}{n}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} 1$